# Sort names with lambda in reverse from generic class

Tags: java, sorting, generics

In my taks I need to sort list in reverse alphabetic order from generic class.

Class has parameter:

```
public class CarSaloon<T extends Car>

private List<T> listOfCars:

public CarSaloon(){this.listOfCars= new ArrayList<T>;} + get and set
```

In main I have list of cars and I did this:

```
List<CarSaloon> listSorting = (List<CarSaloon>) carSaloon.getListOfCars
.stream
.sorted(Comparator.comparing(Car::getName).reversed())
.collect(Collectors.toList());
```

My input:

Porsche->Audi->Bmw

Result should be:

Porsche->Bmw->Audi

But it gives me reversed input:
Bmw->Audi->Porsche

Edit:

I print it like this:

```
for(Car c:listSorting)
 System.out.println(c.toString());
```

Reverse just do that order is backwards, but I need to sort it alphabeticaly

Comment: Your code is very confusing and doesn't look like it's doing what you think it does: you are mixing up `List<CarShop>` and `List<Car>`.

Comment: But CarShop is generic list and I need to sort that class which extend with T class Car.
I know class CarShop should be CarSaloon>Car. This is just example i wrote. I edited post, hope it is more clear now

Comment: `listSorting` should be of type `List<Car>`, because it contains cars, not CarSaloons.

Comment: That's why Intellij cast is after =

Comment: As @LouisWasserman mentioned the main issue is with incorrect type of list, which should be: `List<Car> listSorting = (List<Car>) carSaloon.getListOfCars();`  Then sorting works fine: `CarSaloon carSaloon = new CarSaloon();
      carSaloon.setListOfCars(Arrays.asList(new Car("Audi"), new Car("Porsche"), new Car("BMW")));`  sorted output: `Car: Porsche  -> Car: BMW  -> Car: Audi`

Comment: I have one more question, what if i want to sort with colletctions.sort in class where I dont have list (sort names in like previous example)

Comment: Meaning??  [Collections.sort](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List)) accepts  `List<T>` parameter, where T needs to extend Comparable.  Or custom comparator may be provided.  `Set` has sorted version `TreeSet` which can accept custom Comparator too.

Comment: I have to make function which sends list to class where I sort it

Comment: List<Car> still reverse order not by name

Answer (score 0):

You should override the compare method from `Comparator` in the way that you want to get your results to be. Simply your class should `implement Comparator` and add:

```
@Override
    public int compare(ClassName car1, ClassName car2) {
        String carName1= car1.getCar();
        String carName2 = car2.getCar();

        // ascending order (descending order would be: name2.compareTo(name1))
        return name1.compareTo(name2);
    }
```

If it won't give you the output that you want - modify it.

Comment: That is another task, I did that already but it definitely helps!

Comment: Can I do it with if T extends class Car ?

Comment: @sdavb Sure, you should do it like `public class SomeClass<T extends Fragment & SomeInterface>`. Hope I have helped you in any way :)

Comment: We do it like that when you want to get result like "T must extend Fragment and implement SomeInterface"

Comment: I'll try with that